# How to use action and outlet for same button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction, iboutlet

I have a like button having an image to it and i have to put some action in that button after tapping it, action such as getting likes count and showing it out on that button (likes count). Doing this i am getting an error that outlets cannot be connected to the repeating content.Suggest me something how would i do that.

```
// here is my code how i am doing it but its giving me storyboard error

- (IBAction)likeButtonAction:(id)sender {

    if(_likeButtonOutlet.selected) {

        NSManagedObject *record = [self.fetchedResultsController valueForKey:@"total_likes"];   

        //here on the above line i am fetching the count of likes and below i am sitting it to the button outlet

        [_likeButtonOutlet setValue:record forKey:@"total_likes"];

    }

}
```

Comment: In UIButton use only one Outlet Connection and one Action Connection, don't use more than one, if you check the Bool variable Condition in single action.

Comment: Are you using custom table view cell in which _dislikeButtonOutlet is present?

Comment: @pkc456  that like button is in custom table view cell

Comment: You need to connect your outlet to the custom cell not to the view controller.
Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep a reference to the UIButton, you can simply access the `sender`.

```
- (IBAction)likeButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSInteger totalLikes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"total_likes"];

    if (sender.selected) {
        sender.selected = NO;
        totalLikes--;
    } else {
        sender.selected = YES;
        totalLikes++;
    }

    [sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Likes %ld", (long)totalLikes] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:totalLikes forKey:@"total_likes"];
}
```

Comment: @ guidev  it is giving me error this class is not key value coding for key "total_likes'

Comment: no its giving same error this class is not key value coding for key "total_likes' @guidev

Comment: what class is `_likeButtonOutlet`?

Comment: _likeButtonoutlet is not class its outlet of button and i think it is giving error because we are fetching valueForKey "total_likes" @guidev

Comment: _likeButtonoutlet is a `UIButton` or a custom class? Because if it's a simple `UIButton`, your code should get the same error.

Comment: ok. I assumed that you created a custom UIButton. See the updated code

Comment: no i cannot do like this and thanks you are helping me...but i am using codeData and there i have saved the "total_likes" count so have to fetch that and show it to the like button having an image @guidev

Comment: Since I don't have access to your full code, I provided a simple implementation of the key concept. Getting the value from Core Data and setting the image is up to you. :)

Comment: and should i use sender instead of button outlet @guidev

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have `_dislikeButtonOutlet` in custom cell. You have mistakenly connect it to the `view controller`.

> You need to connect your outlet to the custom cell not to the view
>   controller

Comment: how to connect it to cell @pkc456

Comment: Create the IBOutlet at table cell in the similar fashion as you did in view controller. Don't forget to remove _likeButtonOutlet at view controller

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect your button outlet to the custom cell class. Click the assistant editor

[image]
 then open custom cell like this

[image]
 then connect the button outlet to customCell class. 
then at tableview delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath.. add following code

```
 cell.likeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeBtnClicked), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

then define the func likeBtnClicked in your view controller. then put the code of likeButtonAction inside likeBtnClicked. Hope it helps.